# 'FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory' when trying to convert images in directory from JPG to PNG files

Tags: python, operating-system

I am new to Python, and I am trying to convert all images in my file (JPG) to PNG format.

I am using this code:

```
from PIL import Image
import os

#Image directory
directory = "D:\\weeds"

for filename in os.listdir(directory): 
    if filename.endswith(".jpg"): 
        prefix = filename.split(".jpg")[0]
        im = Image.open(filename)
        im.save(prefix+'.png')  
    else: 
        continue
```

However, the following error is generated:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-871d84dccfb2> in <module>
      7     if filename.endswith(".jpg"):
      8         prefix = filename.split(".jpg")[0]
----> 9         im = Image.open(filename)
     10         im.save(prefix+'.png')
     11     else:

~\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in open(fp, mode)
   2876 
   2877     if filename:
-> 2878         fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
   2879         exclusive_fp = True
   2880 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'weed0.jpg'
```

This image is clearly in my directory:

[image]

How can I fix this error, and convert all JPG images to PNG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `os.listdir` gives you the leaf file names. It does not give you the full paths. For example, in your case, the directory is `"D:\\weeds"`, so any results from `os.listdir` would give you names such `"foo"` or `"bar"` but not `"D:\\weeds\foo"`. In order to use the results of `os.listdir` from any working directory, you need to use `os.path.join` with `"D:\\weeds"` to form the full, correct path.

Comment: Thank you. In my code, do I just replace ```os.listdir(D:\\weeds)``` with ```os.path.join(D:\\weeds)```?  I'm not sure exactly where to put it, since I'm new to the ```os``` module.

Comment: no, `os.path.join` returns a new path you can then pass to your `open` function, like `Image.open(os.path.join("D:\\weeds", filename))`